# How to include the fixed population size in R

Tags: r, sampling

I have a quite dumb question. I have a data with 70 rows (objects) and I have to find simple random sampling without replacement with the sample size of 10. I've forgotten how things work in R so I cannot remember how to incorporate all rows (objects) and I have not found a good way to google it (since it's so trivial, i guess)

In order to perform sampling, I'm planning to use **srswor(n,N)**, I just need the N to in incorporate all the objects (rows) and make a subdataset out of it.

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: `mysample <- df[sample(nrow(df), 10), ]`

Comment: nrow(data) also helped me